# Can R code be compiled?

Tags: r

Is it possible to compile R into something like an executable or similar? I know R is an interpreted language but still. Any workarounds?

I've two objectives here & a solution catering to any one or both is OK:

1. To allow the code to be run on a machine that may not have R installed
2. To hide the actual logic / algorithms being used from the person using it.

Re. #2 I'm not assuming someone who'd take the pains to decompile, reverse engineer, read assembly etc. But just to prevent a cursory user from just stealing the R code verbatim.

The exact platform the program must run on is fully known in advance. So platform independence is not of concern here.

Is this too much to ask for? Must I prototype in R and then switch to an actual compiled language?

Comment: To make the code portable look into [Introducing Rocker: Docker for R](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2014/10/23/)

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not aware of any possibility to create something comparable to a Python frozen binary with `R`.

Comment: "stealing R code"… one of the whole goals of R is to enable sharing of info/knowledge. If you really need your "IP" protected, make your app a Shiny app and let folks run it in the cloud.